# How to add multiple values of same key in python dictionary

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, dictionary, python-3.8

I have dictionary like this.

```
dict1 = {'key1': [1,2,3,4] , 'key2': [5,6,7]}
```

I want output like this.

```
dict1 = {'key1': 10 , 'key2': 18}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
dict1 = {'key1': [1,2,3,4] , 'key2': [5,6,7]}
{k:sum(v) for k,v in dict1.items()}
```

First your extract the keys and values from your dictionary, then you sum the values as output.

```
dict1.items()
dict_items([('key1', [1, 2, 3, 4]), ('key2', [5, 6, 7])])
```

As you can see you get a tuple. By saying `for k,v in dict1.items()`, you are extracting those `k`,`v`  then you are summing the `v`...
Hope you understand.